# Removing axis labels matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this image and I don't know how to remove the axis labels from the top and right hand side.

[image]

I have tried:

```
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

and

```
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("left")
ax.xaxis.set_label_position("bottom")
```

and

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', left='off', top='off', right='off', bottom='off', labelleft='off', labeltop='off', labelright='off', labelbottom='off')
```

This is my code for plotting:

```
 ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

 plt.pcolormesh(reflon, reflat, par_interp, vmin=0, vmax=2, cmap=plt.cm.jet, 
 transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 

 plt.colorbar()

 rowskip = 50
 colskip = 50 
 plt.quiver(reflon[0::rowskip,0::colskip],reflat[0::rowskip,0::colskip],
           u[0::rowskip,0::colskip],v[0::rowskip,0::colskip], 
           color='black',pivot='middle', alpha=0.7, width=0.015, units='inches', 
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

 ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                     linewidth=0.5, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')

 ax.coastlines()
 figtitle = siteid+': HS (m MSL) and Wnd: '+dstr
 ax.set_title(figtitle)

 dtlabel = datetime.date.strftime(dt,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
 dtlabel = dtlabel[0:8]+'_'+dtlabel[8:14]
 filenm = dtlabel+'.png'
 plt.show()
 plt.savefig(filenm,dpi=150,bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.5)
```

Also, if you know how to make it so the east coast of the US is not red, let me know. Trying to figure that out too. Might be an issue with the data I am plotting though.

Comment: You are using cartopy.  Please read the cartopy docs for how to remove the upper and right hand grid labels.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://pythonguides.com/matplotlib-remove-tick-labels/), you could simply color the labels `white` by

`plt.xticks(color='w')` and `plt.yticks(color='w')`

with `plt` = `matplotlib.pyplot`

Answer (score -1):

Found answer here  https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/gridliner.html

```
   gl.xlabels_top = False
   gl.ylabels_right = False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: Also, `gl` is not defined (did I oversee it?). Defining gl would be nice.